# Using JavaScript Countdown timer in html5 mobile app

Tags: javascript, performance, sencha-touch-2, web-worker, countdowntimer

I need to implement a countdown timer in my html5 (sencha touch 2) mobile application.

Currently, I have used a JavaScript function that updates the timer every second via setInterval function and then updates the html content.

```
function updateTimer() {
now      = new Date();
kickoff  = Date.parse("August 15, 2013 09:00:00");
diff = kickoff - now;

days  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60*24) );
hours = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60) );
mins  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60) );
secs  = Math.floor( diff / 1000 );

dd = days;
hh = hours - days  * 24;
mm = mins  - hours * 60;
ss = secs  - mins  * 60;

Ext.getCmp('countdownText').setHtml('<span class="text"><p class="val">'+dd+'</p><p class="type_days">Days</p></span><span class="text"><p class="val">'+hh+'</p><p class="type_hours">Hours</p></span><span class="text"><p class="val">'+mm+'</p><p class="type_minutes">Minutes</p></span><span class="text"><p class="val">'+ss+'</p><p class="type_seconds">Seconds</p></span>');

 setInterval('updateTimer()', 1000 );           }
```

> My question is, will this have an impact on the performance of the
>   application?

Will **html5 Web Workers** be more efficient?

Is there any other approach by which I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: The function doesn't do very much, so I wouldn't expect a performance problem. What happened when you tried it? (By the way, passing a function reference to `setInterval()` rather than a string is best practice: `setInterval(updateTimer, 1000 );`.)

Comment: As of now, I have just started building a mobile app using Sencha Touch 2. And the countdown timer is one of the first components that I am implementing. What I was wondering was, will this approach (assuming code is optimized as suggested by Graham) impact performance at a later point when there are other features implemented as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things you can do to vastly improve performance:

1st, Your variables never had `var` declarations... so all of these variables exist within the window scope which needs to change!  Terribly bad practice and can lead to unexpected bugs.

2nd, `kickoff` should be a variable outside of the function as there's no need to parse a string and construct a new date object EVERY second.

3rd, don't save a 'now' variable as you never use it again.  Do `diff = kickoff - Date.now()`

4th, When you update countdownText, you're passing in A LOT of markup.  This requires the DOM to remove elements in the tree, perform a repaint AND a reflow, then add a bunch of new elements to the tree, and perform a repaint AND an expensive reflow (which normally is OK but EVERY second is a huge performance hit).  You should try and break this down to just updating the text nodes.  So, you should have 4 `setHTML` calls where you update JUST the text and those `setHTML` calls are attached to elements associated with days, hours, minutes, and seconds respectively.

Lastly, pass `updateTimer` into setInterval and not `'updateTimer()'`.

That is all!  Hoep that helps and ask any questions in the comments :)

Comment: And to expand upon the answer, WebWorkers are good too, but your biggest performance hit is your manipulation of the DOM, which WebWorkers won't help with.  Also, WebWorkers are expensive to start so, unless you're doing some intensive number crunching or need to perform animations in the DOM without interruption, WebWorkers generally aren't needed.

Comment: Thanks a ton for those suggestions. The JavaScript code is something I picked up from a blog. So I dint really look into the details. I was pondering whether the approach itself was good enough compared to Web Workers or other approaches.
But your suggestions are totally valid and will be of great help.
Thanks again :)